# How to map a json that I don't know the number of the parameters

Tags: ios, json, swift, object, mapper

Hello I have a json the returns me some parameters as variables. 
It has Parameter1, Parameter2, Parameter3 etc.. 
I don't know how many parameters will it give me. It's not a list it's just different variables in the json.

Which is the best way to map a json like that? I use Object Mapper

For Example:

First Time the json is

```
 {
  "MyObject": {
    "Parameter1": "p1",
    "Parameter2": "p2",
    "Parameter3": "p3",
    "Parameter4": "p4"
  }
}
```

And a second time the json is

```
{
  "MyObject": {
    "Parameter1": "p1",
    "Parameter2": "p2",
    "Parameter3": "p3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the JSON sample of it?

Comment: I edited it check, thank you @AbhirajsinhThakore

Comment: How does your app know which properties to access? Is it a fixed list of known names?

Comment: I don't know I will try to map a fixed number of properties for example the first five Parameter1, Parameter 2... and If there were more, their problem. But I want to know if there is a way to map these properties by using something like map["Parameter*"]

Comment: Well you could convert the json to a dictionary and loop over the key and values

Comment: Perfect answer that was what I was looking, post it as an answer to mark it as solved. J. Doe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
let keyvalue = parentDict.value(forKey: "MyObject") as! NSDictionary
                var lastValue = Keyvalue.allValues
                var lastKey = Keyvalue.allKeys

                for Keyname in Keyvalue.allKeys
                {
                    print("Keyname %@",Keyname)
                    print("Value %@",Keyvalue.value(forKey:Keyname))
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

the first step to parse any JSON to make it reusable is to create your Model class or struct accordingly.

1. Create a class called `MyObject` as same as your json dictionary
2. Create a let/var property `parameters: [String]?`. It's optional as API isn't reliable and maybe wont send anything at all.
3. See the example below how I parse the json object below.

   ```
   class MyObject {
      let parameters: [String]?

      // it's failable because maybe json different at runtime & couldn't parse
      init?(json: [String:AnyObject]) {
         var key = "Parameter"
         var parms = [String]()
         for i in 0..<json.count {
            guard let item = json["\(key)\(i+1)"] as? String else { continue }
            params.append(item)
         }
         self.parameters = params
      }

   }
   ```

Now you can access the parameters array with index.

Well this could be refactored and you can get the idea how you will handle this with that library.